# Cann't create new project in Android Studio 3.0 Beta1

Tags: android, android-studio, beta

When click "Next" button on the following dialog while creating new android project, the dialog is shaken and can not go next.
Is it may something wrong in my config or is there any known issue?

I'm using Android Studio 3.0 Beta 1. Please help. Thanks you.

[image]

Comment: Does that happens with all the activities or only with empty activity???

Comment: Yes, all Activity @SnehalGongle. Even with 'No Activity'.

Comment: What do you mean by the dialog is shaken???

Comment: Yes. I tried by selecting all the Activities provided on the dialog and it happened the same; the dialog is shaken(vibrated) and did not perform nothing. But, when I open the existing project, it is OK and can do development.

Comment: maybe your sdk location may have changed please also delete your .gradle folder from C:\Users\gongl\.gradle

Comment: I checked and tried according to your instruction, @SnehalGongle. It is still happening the same issue. I also deleted my old .AndroidStudioPreview3.0 config files and it still not working.

Comment: Yay!!! Now I got it SnehalGongle. You are right, bro. It is caused of gradle folder. Normally, I always use gradle from my custom location and I renamed 'gradle' folder that came together with Android Studio to something like 'unusedgradle'. It is working proper in previous Android Studio version. I have no idea why this is not working in this version Android Studio. Now, I re-renamed the 'unusedgradle' folder to it's original name  'gradle' and now I can create new project. Thanks @Snehal Gongle.

Comment: Cool, Happy to help...

Answer (score 0):

Create gradle folder in android studio install folder. In my case renamed gradle to xgradle and windows create proyect vibrated.